# I am trying to open a site in headless mode but it seems to be stuck at a radical loop, how do I solve it?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, headless

I am trying to open a site in headless mode but it seems to be stuck at a radical loop, how do I solve it?
This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

web = "https://www.powerplay.com/sportsbook/SOCCER/"
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.headless = True

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get(web)
```

The error that i get:

```
[0605/021633.437:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'interest-cohort'.", source:  (0)
[0605/021634.456:INFO:CONSOLE(5)] "'window.webkitStorageInfo' is deprecated. Please use 'navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage' or 'navigator.webkitPersistentStorage' instead.", source:  (5)
[0605/021637.724:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'interest-cohort'.", source:  (0)
[0605/021638.445:INFO:CONSOLE(5)] "'window.webkitStorageInfo' is deprecated. Please use 'navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage' or 'navigator.webkitPersistentStorage' instead.", source:  (5)
[0605/021641.860:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'interest-cohort'.", source:  (0)
[0605/021642.577:INFO:CONSOLE(5)] "'window.webkitStorageInfo' is deprecated. Please use 'navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage' or 'navigator.webkitPersistentStorage' instead.", source:  (5)
[0605/021645.992:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'interest-cohort'.", source:  (0)
[0605/021646.629:INFO:CONSOLE(5)] "'window.webkitStorageInfo' is deprecated. Please use 'navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage' or 'navigator.webkitPersistentStorage' instead.", source:  (5)
[0605/021650.126:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'interest-cohort'.", source:  (0)
[0605/021650.798:INFO:CONSOLE(5)] "'window.webkitStorageInfo' is deprecated. Please use 'navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage' or 'navigator.webkitPersistentStorage' instead.", source:  (5)
[0605/021654.261:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'interest-cohort'.", source:  (0)
[0605/021701.759:INFO:CONSOLE(5)] "'window.webkitStorageInfo' is deprecated. Please use 'navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage' or 'navigator.webkitPersistentStorage' instead.", source:  (5)
[0605/021709.680:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'interest-cohort'.", source:  (0)
```

and it keeps repeating

Answer (score 1):

I tried adding this and it works

```
chrome_options.add_argument('--log-level=1')
```

Source [List of Chromium Command Line Switches](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#log-level)

```
log-level: Sets the minimum log level.
Valid values are from 0 to 3: 

    INFO = 0 (default)
    WARNING = 1
    LOG_ERROR = 2
    LOG_FATAL = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: this can be fixed by adding the following header to your site:

```
permissions-policy: interest-cohort=()
```

This header can be used to block Google's [FLoC](https://web.dev/floc/), which is causing your issue.

Comment: I'm sorry if I sound stupid, but how do I add an header to the site? Also, it's a random site, not mine...